# Tomcat response headers of css file with content-type is text/html

Tags: java, css, jsp, tomcat

I have a java web application and in a jsp file I have a link tag to reference css files but Tomcat server responses it with content-type html so browser can't load it.

Here's my project structure

[image]

When type localhost:8080/QLPhongBan/, it will call HomePageServlet.java and it forwards to home.jsp file.

home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="vi">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Trang chu</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:include page="_header.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <jsp:include page="_sidebar.jsp"></jsp:include>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the style.css in link tag was loaded in browser with content-type is html

[image: browser load style.css]

I tried add mime-mapping in web.xml but it did not work.

So how can I load this css file? Any help will be approciated!

And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: did you copy the css file directly into the project folder ?

Comment: @PacMan No, I created it with NetBeans IDE, new Cascading Style Sheet file